# Label two equations in one line with two correct reference?

Tags: equations, labels

I have searched the website about this but have found nothing similar. suppose that I have two equations a=b (1) and b=c (2). I would like to be able to put both of them in one line with two different references as:
a = b, b = c (1, 2)

Answer (score 3):

I'm prety sure, that your question is duplicate, but I can't found (my) answer on similar question ... So, meanwhile see, if this is what you looking for:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
    \setlength\PreviewBorder{3mm}

\begin{document}
\begin{preview}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XX}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:1}
    a=b
\end{equation}
    &
\begin{equation}\label{eq:2}
    c=d
\end{equation}
\end{tabularx}\par
Considering \eqref{eq:1}, \eqref{eq:2} and (\ref{eq:1},\ref{eq:2}) \dots
\end{preview}
\end{document}
```

Use of preview is only to shof this equation fragment. In real use, remove all it appearance.

Comment: I have already seen this question but if you see my question I have mentioned two labels in one parenthesis as (1, 2).

Comment: Than please correct title of your question and also make question clear. It seems that haven't problem with two equation in line but with referencing range of equations ... see edit of mine answer.

Comment: looks good to me

Comment: what if I have to write **and** between the two equations?

Comment: @ManjoyDas, if you have new question, please ask it as such. I guess that you like to insert third column where you like to write *and*.