# Inserting text between two labelled equation in a single line

Tags: equations, labels

I read [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/320178/label-two-equations-in-one-line-with-two-correct-reference/320179?noredirect=1#comment1484842_320179) how to create a single line with multiple labelled equations. But I want to add a text between each of the two consecutive equations like 'and', 'or' etc. How do I do this?

Comment: You can add a column between the columns that contain the equations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to align the material in the equations and the intermediate phrase  ("and", "or", etc), I'd encase each equation in a `minipage`.

[image]

Encasing the `minipage`-encased equations in a `center` environment will assure adequate vertical separation to the material above or below the equations.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
  \begin{equation}\label{eq:1} 
    a=b
  \end{equation}
\end{minipage}
\hfill and
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
  \begin{equation}\label{eq:2} 
    c=d
  \end{equation}%
\end{minipage}%
\end{center}

\noindent
Considering equations (\ref{eq:1}) and (\ref{eq:2}), \dots
\end{document}
```